# Objects Disappear on Camera View - Pressing "0" Key

Tags: modeling

I'm puzzled why my ojects disappear whenever I press "0" key to preview camera angle. I've set my camera to 50mm and LOCK CAMERA TO VIEW. Cannot figure it out. They all disappear when I zoom out.

By the way, I have set my unit of measurement to IMPERIAL. Is this a problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to decrease the "Start" value and/or increase the "End" value in Clipping section of your camera settings.

[image: Camera settings]

Comment: okay, figured it out. your were right @ExConfessor thanks